# Django - CreateView - How to declare variable and use it in templates

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-generic-views

How do I declare a variable in Django's Createview, so I can use it from its template?
For example I want to use {{ place_slug }} in the template. I pass that from urls.py like below:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^new/(?P<place_slug>[\w\-\_]+)/?$', PictureCreateView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-new'),
)
```

views.py:

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Picture

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.place = get_object_or_404(Place, slug=kwargs['place_slug'])
        return super(PictureCreateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        more code here
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `PictureCreateView.dispatch` from your urls.py?

Comment: as_view is [correct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Override get_context_data and set context_data['place_slug'] = your_slug

Something like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['place_slug'] = self.place.slug
    return context
```

Some more info on this in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context).

Answer (score 0):

in template you can use `{{ title }}`

```
class Something(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'app/example.html'
        model = models.SomeModel
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(Something, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context["title"] = "Some title"
            return context
```