# Django Generic Createview : Add another object to template

Tags: django, forms, subclassing, django-generic-views, createobject

I'm trying to add additional data to my template named "equipment_form" linked with my view CreateEquipment (CreateView generic django)

So, my model Equipment possess a subcategory. And my model subcategory possess a category.

For UX reasons, I want my user to chose the category of the equipment first, then the subcategory.  In order to do this, I need to get in the view the whole content of the
category table and give it to the template. And I have some trouble to figure out how I can do it.

I will really appreciate the help of the community! Thank you.

So atm my view look like this :

```
class EquipmentCreate(CreateView):
   #category list not passed to the template
   category_list = Category.objects.all()
   model = Equipment
   success_url = reverse_lazy('stock:equipment-list')
```

EDIT : I found the answer here :

[Django - CreateView - How to declare variable and use it in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552337/django-createview-how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-templates?rq=1)

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Glad you found the answer -- you may want to paste a small snippet of your solution as the answer, so the question stops showing up on 'unanswered' lists.  :)

Comment: I found My answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552337/django-createview-how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-templates?rq=1

Finally it's not so hard :)

Answer (score 0):

Found<sup>*</sup> the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552423/):

> Override get_context_data and set context_data['place_slug'] = your_slug
>
> Something like this:
>
> ```
> def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
>     context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
>     context['place_slug'] = self.place.slug
>     return context
> ```
>
> Some more info on this in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context).

<sub>*Posting OP's comment and edit as answer</sub>